# Can we specify the amount to be charged by iPhone storekit framework?

Tags: iphone, e-commerce, payment, storekit

Can we specify the amount to be charged by iPhone storekit framework ?
or it will charge the amount specified at the application creation time ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The amount charged is based on an item's price tier.  You set the tier in iTunes connect, and can change it after the application is created.  To show the current price to the user, look at [the documentation for `SKProduct`'s `price` property](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKProduct_Reference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKProduct/price).

Comment: ok thanks ,
can you elaborate it with sample code how can i make purchase app from my application thru storekit framework.
i have setup test user,

Comment: Take a look at the In App Purchasing Programming Guide, especially the "Adding a Store to Your Application" section - http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/AddingaStoretoYourApplication/AddingaStoretoYourApplication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH101-SW2